# VBA webservcie call takes time and excel goes to Not responding

Tags: vba, excel, webservice-client, webservices-client

I have this web-service call in excel through VBA.

```
Req.Open "POST", MyURL, False
Req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

Req.send (sReq)
```

In this **Req.send (sReq)** takes time to respond when **sReq** length is too much. During this time excel goes not responding and then comes back to live and proceed to next line in the code.

Can you suggest how can I stop my excel going to Not responding on this step ?

Comment: Dim Req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
       Dim MyURL, sReq As String

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the out of the box Excel/VBA.

To keep excel responsive during the web request you would need it to execute asynchronously (on a separate thread) but since VBA runs on a single thread this is not possible.

You could however write a VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) add in for excel using VB.NET or C#.NET, this could add custom ribbon tab where you can put a button to initiate your web request asynchronously.

Comment: Can we do the same and come back to do the remaining task here ? i.e. Response from web request can be used back in VBA ? Do you have a same code for that ?

Comment: I don't think so but there may be a way to make your API call asynchronously in an Add-In and then execute a VBA macro or function to do the post processing with your result.  You could always just process your result from within the add in too. Without knowing more about what you are doing it is difficult to advise.

Comment: @GovindarajThangavel I can see if I can post some code to get you started with an add-in but would need to use C#.NET for the add in and I am conscious this is a Excel/VBA question.  Are you OK with C#?

Comment: Am unaware of C# coding. So its not my cup of tea :) I will use my current coding as it is. Thanks for your time.